# No instance for (Num int) arising from the literal `0'

Tags: haskell

I have a simple function and get a compiled error like the following:

```
fac::[int] -> int
fac [] = 0
fac (x:[]) = x
fac ([xs]) =  sum [xs]
```

Compile error:

```
  No instance for (Num int) arising from the literal `0'
    Possible fix:
      add (Num int) to the context of
        the type signature for fac :: [int] -> int
    In the expression: 0
    In an equation for `fac': fac [] = 0
```

What is wrong with the codes?

Answer (score 13):

The type signature is wrong.  `int` (lower case `i`) is a "type variable" which means this function should be polymorphic for any type `[sometype] -> sometype`.  Instead you probably wanted `Int` (capital `I`) which refers to signed integers of a bit length that depends on your compiler and platform.

Another issue, a common mistake, is the last pattern will never match because it specifies a list with one element.  That is, `x:[]` is a single element list where the name `x` is bound to the element.  Similarly, `[xs]` is a single element list (syntactic sugar for `xs:[]`) where `xs` is bound to the one element.

Answer (score 5):

First, you want the type, `Int`, with a capital letter.

```
fac :: [Int] -> Int
```

Next, your patterns overlap. Anything that matches `[xs]` also matches `x:[]`, and vice-versa. It sort of looks like you want to match

```
fac xs = sum xs
```

… only that just makes `fac = sum`.

Answer (score 1):

Just one thing to add to the other answers: if you actually want `fac` to work on all numeric types, you can add the `Num` constraint to the type signature as the error message suggests. In that case it would be better to use a less confusing type variable than `int`:

```
fac :: Num a => [a] -> a
```